# Injecting another project in mojo

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I am trying to develop a mojo, where i am injecting my project in my plugin to list out all the dependencies defined in the project.

```
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", required = true, readonly = true)
private MavenProject project;
```

Is it possible to inject another project ? For e.g. i have 1 project 
A it has sub project X, Y and Z. When the plugin executed i would like the project Y also injected in my plugin, so that i can get dependencies from that project as well. I tried something like this.

```
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", property = "other.project", required = true, readonly = true)
private MavenProject project2;
```

But doesnot seems to be working. project2 is always null.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You can only inject the project you are currently running in...You seemded to misunderstand this concept?

Comment: I am working on gigaspace based project, according to the guidelines, we should our unit tests against the actual space instance. Now GS provides a class which helps deployment in a non-managed environment but it requires either fat jar or i an open directory structutre but i have to manually add dependencies to the class path. 

So lets say my project X is executed before that space needs to be up i.e. jar of project Y must be deployed. So in my plugin idea was to somehow inject project Y deploy it and then deploy project X

Comment: You can use `mvn dependency:tree` to see all dependencies of your project..furthermore you can use a parameter of the maven-[dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) to write the information into a file via `mvn dependency:tree -DoutputFile=tree.lst` etc.. You can of course create a `fatjar` via usual maven plugins ...Apart from that maven-dependency-plugin contains a goal `build-classpath` which generated the classpath of your project...Why i don't understand is the need for your second project?